# Has the maximum video width for raspivid been increased beyond the original 2048?

Tags: streaming-video, raspivid

I'm using the 12 MP image sensor and the latest version of raspbian on a Pi Zero 2 W. I'd like to  use raspivid to create a (width = 2 x 1920) x (height = 1/2 x 1080) h264 video. I've seen statements from several years ago that raspivid is hard coded to a limit of 2048 pixels wide, and that h264 can only support up to the number of 16x16 macro blocks contained within 2048x1024. However, I've also seen recent statements that h264 can handle 4K video, or up to 16K in some cases, which are well beyond that limit.

I'm considering using the timelapse mode in raspistill to create a series of jpegs with my desired resolution, and feeding them into ffmpeg to create h264, but I tested raspistill in timelapse mode and the maximum rate is only about 1.5 frames per second without dropping frames.

Is the maximum h264 video width in raspivid still 2048 ? Is it being increased since it's not a limit in h264 ?

Is there anything else I can do to increase the frame rate above about 1.5 fps with my target resolution ?

Thank you in advance for your help.